# C++ style cast from unsigned char * to const char *

Tags: c++, constants, casting

I have:

```
unsigned char *foo();
std::string str;
str.append(static_cast<const char*>(foo()));
```

The error: `invalid static_cast from type ‘unsigned char*’ to type ‘const char*’`

What's the correct way to cast here in C++ style?

Comment: unsigned char has been typically used for holding unicode style strings, are you sure you want to directly cast it rather converting the contents?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

reinterpret_cast

Comment: @jesses.co.tt Thanks for the downvote. The key feature of this post that makes it get upvoted is its timeliness. The other answers provide various detail and are best read and upvoted separately. If [@JaredPars answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/658924/11635) covers what you're looking for, I'd use that and/or upvote it. You'll note I've invested the time to improve the format of those too. I really don't see the point of expanding this answer to encompass the content of the others.

Comment: ok, I understand you're rationale here, and taken as a whole page, I agree that there was no need to re-articulate... I guess it's hard to take the time and look at the entire page and the timestamps instead of judging each answer on its own merit... but point taken (especially from someone who has 55x more reputation from me!)

Comment: @jesses.co.tt Don't worry, I understand your perspective and you're not far wrong. To be honest it's been a long time since I 'competed' in high traffic tags with fastest-gun-in-the-west responses like this. But you don't get this level of rep by deleting your answer even if that's the right thing to do (which on another day I'd be arguing just as happily!). Right, we have a wall of text cluttering the place, so your mission is accomplished :P

Comment: I especially like how you were so concerned with shouting "FIRST!" that you didn't even bother with `basic formatting`.

Comment: This is a truly useless "answer".  It simply provides no information.

Comment: @RubenBartelink why bother answering then if your answer adds nothing and cannot stand on its own? if you don't see why this answer needs expanding, maybe you should remove it.

Answer (score 65):

`char *` and `const unsigned char *` are considered unrelated types. So you want to use `reinterpret_cast`.

But if you were going from `const unsigned char*` to a non `const` type you'd need to use `const_cast` first. `reinterpret_cast` cannot cast away a `const` or `volatile` qualification.

Comment: "Unrelated" is misleading here: it makes an impression you cannot cast from one to another. I'm reading a draft of 2014, "3.9.1 Fundamental types", and it says: "A `char`, a `signed char`, and an `unsigned char` occupy the same amount of storage and have the same alignment requirement". This IS a relationship. Or here's a more readable link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Character_types

Answer (score 57):

Try `reinterpret_cast`

```
unsigned char *foo();
std::string str;
str.append(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(foo()));
```

Answer (score 20):

unsigned char* is basically a byte array and should be used to represent raw data rather than a string generally.  A unicode string would be represented as wchar_t*

According to the C++ standard a reinterpret_cast between unsigned char* and char* is safe as they are the same size and have the same construction and constraints.  I try to avoid reintrepret_cast even more so than const_cast in general.

If static cast fails with what you are doing you may want to reconsider your design because frankly if you are using C++ you may want to take advantage of what the "plus plus" part offers and use string classes and STL (aka std::basic_string might work better for you)

Answer (score 6):

You would need to use a `reinterpret_cast<>` as the two types you are casting between are unrelated to each other.

Answer (score 6):

Too many comments to make to different answers, so I'll leave another answer here.

You can and should use `reinterpret_cast<>`, in your case

```
str.append(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(foo()));
```

because, while these two are different types, the 2014 standard, chapter `3.9.1 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental]` says **there is** a relationship between them:

> Plain `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are three distinct types, collectively called narrow character types. **A `char`, a `signed char`, and an `unsigned char` occupy the same amount of storage and have the same alignment requirements (3.11); that is, they have the same object representation.**

(selection is mine)

Here's an available link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Character_types

Using `wchar_t` for Unicode/multibyte strings is outdated: [Should I use wchar_t when using UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871880/should-i-use-wchar-t-when-using-utf-8)

Answer (score -4):

> Hope it help. :)

```
const unsigned attribName = getname();
const unsigned attribVal = getvalue();
const char *attrName=NULL, *attrVal=NULL;
attrName = (const char*) attribName;
attrVal = (const char*) attribVal;
```