# convert unsigned char* to std::string

Tags: c++, casting, unsigned, tizen

I am little poor in typecasting. I have a string in `xmlChar*` (which is unsigned char*), I want to convert this unsigned char to a `std::string` type.

```
xmlChar* name = "Some data";
```

I tried my best to typecast , but I couldn't find a way to convert it.

Comment: `String or `std::string`? What is `String`, if you don't mean `std::string`?

Comment: Sorry @Mats Petersson, BTW its std::string

Comment: Use reinterpret_cast

See this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658913/c-style-cast-from-unsigned-char-to-const-char][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658913/c-style-cast-from-unsigned-char-to-const-char

Comment: possible duplicate of [const unsigned char \* to std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804123/const-unsigned-char-to-stdstring)

Comment: I can see the reasons why one might want to declare `xmlChar` as an `unsigned char`.  Regretfully, it doesn't work well with any of the standard library: `strlen()` and `std::string` both _require_ `char`.  So if you have any influence at all, change this.  (And XML using `char` is still less painful than Latin-1 using a signed `char`.)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
std::string sName(reinterpret_cast<char*>(name));
```

`reinterpret_cast<char*>(name)` casts from `unsigned char*` to `char*` in an unsafe way but that's the one which should be used here. Then you call the ordinary constructor of `std::string`.

You could also do it C-style  (not recommended):

```
std::string sName((char*) name);
```

Comment: I have found that in some cases, the reinterpret cast produces some junk characters at the end.  Didn't investigate too deeply since they were easy to truncate, but I thought I'd mention it in case I'm not alone.

Comment: Not alone, happened with me too

Comment: You are probably seeing junk because your unsigned char array does not end with a null terminator (or doesn't end with one where you think it does). Generally, just casting from a type to a string type without considering NUL is dangerous and you should think about this carefully if your code is in any way different to OP's example (string **literals** have null terminators already)

Comment: According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1673536/3305789 It seems that some problems can be avoided if you know the size of your string beforehand:
std::string sName(reinterpret_cast<char*>(name), name_len);