# C++ conversion from unsigned char to std::string

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, unsigned-char

Intro: Consider that I have no experience with C++, but can find my way around any language to do basic tasks. 
Most of my experience is with .net languages (vn.net and C#), php and js, so please explain as if you were teaching a complete noob.

Here is the problem: I receive data in an unsigned char characters[12]; and I have to then append that data to a std::string

data is always 12 characters long, and is not null terminated, because it is gathered by selecting specific bytes received from serial port.

Long story short:

```
std::string stroutput = "some text ";
unsigned char characters[12];
characters[0]=64; //demo data to shorten the code
characters[1]=72;
stroutput.append(characters[0]);
stroutput.append(characters[1]);
....
```

The result i want is to have the string value

```
some text @H...
```

But what i get is an error while compiling

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
stroutput.append(characters[0]);
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Logic behind this thinking is that output of:

```
printf("%c%c",characters[0],characters[1]);
```

and

```
std::cout << characters[0] << characters[0] << std::endl;
```

results in

```
@H
```

So: How do I convert unsigned char something[12] to std::string?

Thanks

Edit: Sorry for the duplicate, search didn't return that question.
Thanks everyone - too bad I can't mark multiple answers!

Comment: stroutput.append(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(characters), 12);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append a character you have to use the following overloaded method append

```
basic_string& append(size_type n, charT c);
```

For example

```
stroutput.append(1, characters[0]);
stroutput.append(1, characters[1]);
```

Otherwise use method `push_back` or the `operator +=`. For example

```
stroutput += characters[0];
stroutput += characters[1];
```

If you want to append the whole array or its part then you can write

```
stroutput.append( reinterpret_cast<char *>( characters ), sizeof( characters ) );

stroutput.append( reinterpret_cast<char *>( characters ), n );
```

where n is the number of characters of the array to append.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` has [a constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)r that takes two iterators:

```
stroutput += std::string(characters, characters + 12);
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer especially if buffer is declared as `unsigned char characters[12];`.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, just use [`string::push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/push_back/) instead of [`string::append`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/) - `append` is for concatenating `string`s, whereas `push_back` is for adding characters (and deals with resizing the internals etc).

Using a `string` [constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) is normally a better option but here could cause issues as your array isn't null-terminated (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746688/convert-unsigned-char-to-string)).

Edit: Actually, constructor 5 from the link above (`from-sequence`) should be suitable (if you're willing to cast from `unsigned char *` to `const char *`, which is safe according to [this question+answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078638/can-i-turn-unsigned-char-into-char-and-vice-versa)):

```
std::string stroutput(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(characters), 12);
```

Comment: `std::string stroutput(characters, 12);` won't compile because `characters` because of `unsigned char`

Comment: Every method works, too bad I can't mark multiple answers.

Answer (score 0):

In C++98, the method [`std::string::append`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/) is overloaded with these arguments:

```
(1) string& append (const string& str);
(2) string& append (const string& str, size_t subpos, size_t sublen);
(3) string& append (const char* s);
(4) string& append (const char* s, size_t n);
(5) string& append (size_t n, char c);
(6) template <class InputIterator> string& append (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

And in C++11 and C++14, it is also overloaded with `string& append (initializer_list<char> il);`.

As you can see, there is no candidate for `string& append(unsigned char)`.  The error might come from the compiler failing in overload resolution, trying to use the `(3)` which is for a null-terminated string argument, but fails to find a conversion defined for `unsigned char -> const char *`.

If you still want to use the method `std::string::append`, you can use `(5)`: `string& append (size_t n, char c)` which will append your string with `c` `n` times. In your case, it would be:

```
stroutput.append(1, characters[0]);
stroutput.append(1, characters[1]);
```

The `unsgined char` would be converted into `char`.

Another alternative is to use this [constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) for `std::string`:

```
std::string(characters, characters + 12);
```