# Should I use wchar_t when using UTF-8?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

UTF-8 can encode in 1, 2, and up to 4 bytes. A single `char` on my system is 1 byte. Should I use `wchar_t` as a precaution so that I will be able to fit any arbitrary UTF-8 encoded character?

Comment: It is not necessary. Reference this: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259544/is-wchar-t-needed-for-unicode-support>

Comment: `wchar_t` is (usually?) 2 bytes, not 4.

Comment: No. See http://utf8everywhere.org for what you should do :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you should not! The Unicode 4.0 standard (ISO 10646:2003) notes that:

> The width of `wchar_t` is compiler-specific and can be as small as 8 bits. Consequently, programs that need to be portable across any C or C++ compiler should not use `wchar_t` for storing Unicode text.

Under most circumstances, the "character nature" of UTF-8 text will not be relevant to your program, so treating it as an array of `char` elements, just like any other string, will be sufficient. If you need to extract individual characters, though, those characters should be stored in a type that is at least 24 bits wide (e.g, `uint32_t`), in order to accomodate all Unicode code points.

Answer (score 3):

`wchar_t` is not of much use if you want to make your code portable.

On [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character)

> The width of wchar_t is compiler-specific and can be as small as 8
>   bits. Consequently, programs that need to be portable across any C or
>   C++ compiler should not use wchar_t for storing Unicode text. The
>   wchar_t type is intended for storing compiler-defined wide characters,
>   which may be Unicode characters in some compilers"

Further ,

Both C and C++ introduced fixed-size character types `char16_t` and `char32_t` in the 2011 revisions of their respective standards to provide unambiguous representation of 16-bit and 32-bit Unicode transformation formats, leaving `wchar_t` implementation-defined.