# transform utf-8 lowercase to uppercase

Tags: c++, string, unicode, uppercase, icu

I have some strings in utf-8 format and they have to be converted to uppercase (and / or vice versa).
For the standard ASCII characters this is easy as C++ provides functions for this but for non-ASCII characters (like Cyrillic, Greek, ...) this is a hard problem.
I found the ICU library (see https://unicode-org.github.io, especially https://unicode-org.github.io, https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/, https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/) and an example (https://www.delftstack.com/howto/cpp/how-to-convert-string-to-uppercase-cpp/).

From this I constructed an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
#include <unicode/ustream.h>
#include <unicode/locid.h>

using std::cout; using std::string;
using std::endl; using std::cin;
using std::transform;
using std::toupper;

int main() {
    string string0("hello there είναι απλά ένα κείμενο χωρίς");
    string string1("hallo Привет");
    string string2("Hallo Привет");
    string string3("HALLO ПРИВЕТ");

    icu::UnicodeString unicodeString0(string0.c_str());
    cout << "input string:  " << string0 << endl
        <<  "output string: " << unicodeString0.toUpper() << endl;

    icu::UnicodeString unicodeString1(string1.c_str());
    cout << "input string:  " << string1 << endl
        <<  "output string: " << unicodeString1.toUpper() << endl;

    icu::UnicodeString unicodeString2(string2.c_str());
    cout << "input string:  " << string2 << endl
        <<  "output string: " << unicodeString2.toUpper() << endl;

    icu::UnicodeString unicodeString3(string3.c_str());
    cout << "input string:  " << string3 << endl
        <<  "output string: " << unicodeString3.toUpper() << endl;

    string string4 = "Contrairement à une opinion répandue";

    icu::UnicodeString unicodeString4(string4.c_str());
    cout << "input string:  " << string4 << endl
        << "output string: " << unicodeString4.toUpper() << endl
        << "output string: " << unicodeString4.toUpper("fr-FR") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled it (gcc9.3.0 ICU library 67.1):

```
g++ s2.cpp -licuio -licuuc -o s2
```

and when running I get:

```
input string:  hello there είναι απλά ένα κείμενο χωρίς
output string: HELLO THERE
input string:  hallo Привет
output string: HALLO
input string:  Hallo Привет
output string: HALLO
input string:  HALLO ПРИВЕТ
output string: HALLO
input string:  Contrairement à une opinion répandue
output string: CONTRAIREMENT  UNE OPINION RPANDUE
output string: CONTRAIREMENT  UNE OPINION RPANDUE
```

So we see all the special characters are not shown in the output, I must have missed something (trivial?), though I don't see it.
I'm not limited to the ICU library so other solutions for conversion in C++ between lowercase and uppercase are also welcome.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a unicode String In C++ To Upper Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991431/convert-a-unicode-string-in-c-to-upper-case)

Comment: The base problem is that the special characters seen to be 2-byte characters, thus are not recognized correctly. I'm now looking into `char16_t`->`u16string` but there's no easy way to print those.

Comment: Question is also why it looks like the people at https://www.delftstack.com/howto/cpp/how-to-convert-string-to-uppercase-cpp/ got a right answer.

Comment: Note also you mention only 2-byte characters but I'm not sure whether or not in the 3-byte and 4-byte characters there might also some upper / lower case characters.

Comment: What is the encoding of your source file? What does the compiler think is the encoding of your source file? What is your platform's default codepage (as this is used by `UnicodeString(const char*)`)? Unless they all match, it's not going to work.

Comment: I've been working on this, but the `<locale>` only seems to work with `char` and the non-portable `wchar_t`.. Not new types as `char16_t` and `char32_t`...

Comment: And the codepage of your output view should also match.

Comment: @Codo though I do see the input string correct, how would you implement this (the example is a Cpp program, though the end output is HTML, LaTex, RTF and ...)

Comment: The first step is to understand and control the encoding of the source files, the encoding used by the compiler and the output view. Are you able to do that? If so, what are they? If not, no amount of code will help you.

Comment: All strings will be UTF-8 (input and output).

Comment: Your code runs successfully without changes on my system (macOS) because everything is UTF-8. In your setup there is a mix of encodings and several elements (char constants, `string` constructor, `UnicodeString()` constructor, `cout`) using the platform's default encoding. It's not possible to provide a solution unless we understand what the source code encoding, the compiler's assumption about the source code encoding and the encoding/codepage of the output terminal is.

Comment: Good to know that my code works without problems with macOS. I don't see why this should be locale dependent (but probably a lack in my knowledge). The strings should all be interpreted as UTF-8. The application where the code will be used by a lot of, unknown, people who all can have different locale settings.  As the application is outputting different formats the results should be independent of any locale.

Comment: C++ character constants are locale dependent. C++ strings are locale dependent. The specific `UnicodeString` constructor you have chosen is locale dependent. `cout` is locale dependent. What are you trying to achieve. Possibly most problems are related to this test code and not to the actual task at hand.

Comment: That might indeed be the case. I'll have a go at original code and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Check/Test my code https://repl.it/@JomaCorpFX/ToUpperToLower#main.cpp

For Windows with correct drawing of glyphs/unicode chars(ex. ""), I recomend run your program with the new [Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/).

Read this about Windows's console
[Windows Command-Line: Unicode and UTF-8 Output Text Buffer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-unicode-and-utf-8-output-text-buffer/)

> UPDATE: Added CYGWIN's code and some fixes.

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

// WINDOWS
#if (_WIN32)
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define WINDOWS_PLATFORM 1
#define DLLCALL STDCALL
#define DLLIMPORT _declspec(dllimport)
#define DLLEXPORT _declspec(dllexport)
#define DLLPRIVATE
#define NOMINMAX

#elif __CYGWIN__
#define CYGWIN_PLATFORM 1
#include <windows.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#define DLLCALL CDECL
#define DLLIMPORT
#define DLLEXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#define DLLPRIVATE __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
#define CoTaskMemAlloc(p) malloc(p)
#define CoTaskMemFree(p) free(p)

//EMSCRIPTEN
#elif defined(__EMSCRIPTEN__)
#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#define EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM 1
#define DLLCALL
#define DLLIMPORT
#define DLLEXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#define DLLPRIVATE __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))

// LINUX - Ubuntu, Fedora, , Centos, Debian, RedHat
#elif (__LINUX__ || __gnu_linux__ || __linux__ || __linux || linux)
#define LINUX_PLATFORM 1
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#define DLLCALL CDECL
#define DLLIMPORT
#define DLLEXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#define DLLPRIVATE __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
#define CoTaskMemAlloc(p) malloc(p)
#define CoTaskMemFree(p) free(p)

//ANDROID
#elif (__ANDROID__ || ANDROID)
#define ANDROID_PLATFORM 1
#define DLLCALL
#define DLLIMPORT
#define DLLEXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#define DLLPRIVATE __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))

//MACOS
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#define DLLCALL
#define DLLIMPORT
#define DLLEXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#define DLLPRIVATE __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))
#include "TargetConditionals.h"
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE && TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#define IOS_SIMULATOR_PLATFORM 1
#elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#define IOS_PLATFORM 1
#elif TARGET_OS_MAC
#define MACOS_PLATFORM 1
#else

#endif

#endif

typedef std::string String;
typedef std::wstring WString;

#define EMPTY_STRING u8""s
#define EMPTY_WSTRING L""s

using namespace std::literals::string_literals;

class Strings
{
public:
    static String WideStringToString(const WString &wstr)
    {
        if (wstr.empty())
        {
            return String();
        }
        size_t pos;
        size_t begin = 0;
        String ret;
#if WINDOWS_PLATFORM 

        int size;
        pos = wstr.find(static_cast<wchar_t>(0), begin);
        while (pos != WString::npos && begin < wstr.length())
        {
            WString segment = WString(&wstr[begin], pos - begin);
            size = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, &segment[0], segment.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

            String converted = String(size, 0);
            WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, &segment[0], segment.size(), &converted[0], converted.size(), NULL, NULL);
            ret.append(converted);
            ret.append({0});
            begin = pos + 1;
            pos = wstr.find(static_cast<wchar_t>(0), begin);
        }
        if (begin <= wstr.length())
        {
            WString segment = WString(&wstr[begin], wstr.length() - begin);
            size = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, &segment[0], segment.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
            String converted = String(size, 0);
            WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, &segment[0], segment.size(), &converted[0], converted.size(), NULL, NULL);
            ret.append(converted);
        }
#elif LINUX_PLATFORM || MACOS_PLATFORM || EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM || CYGWIN_PLATFORM
        size_t size;
        pos = wstr.find(static_cast<wchar_t>(0), begin);
        while (pos != WString::npos && begin < wstr.length())
        {
            WString segment = WString(&wstr[begin], pos - begin);
            size = wcstombs(nullptr, segment.c_str(), 0);
            String converted = String(size, 0);
            wcstombs(&converted[0], segment.c_str(), converted.size());
            ret.append(converted);
            ret.append({0});
            begin = pos + 1;
            pos = wstr.find(static_cast<wchar_t>(0), begin);
        }
        if (begin <= wstr.length())
        {
            WString segment = WString(&wstr[begin], wstr.length() - begin);
            size = wcstombs(nullptr, segment.c_str(), 0);
            String converted = String(size, 0);
            wcstombs(&converted[0], segment.c_str(), converted.size());
            ret.append(converted);
        }
#else
        static_assert(false, "Unknown Platform");
#endif
        return ret;
    }

    static WString StringToWideString(const String &str)
    {
        if (str.empty())
        {
            return WString();
        }

        size_t pos;
        size_t begin = 0;
        WString ret;
#if WINDOWS_PLATFORM
        int size = 0;
        pos = str.find(static_cast<char>(0), begin);
        while (pos != std::string::npos)
        {
            std::string segment = std::string(&str[begin], pos - begin);
            std::wstring converted = std::wstring(segment.size() + 1, 0);
            size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, &segment[0], segment.size(), &converted[0], converted.length());
            converted.resize(size);
            ret.append(converted);
            ret.append({0});
            begin = pos + 1;
            pos = str.find(static_cast<char>(0), begin);
        }
        if (begin < str.length())
        {
            std::string segment = std::string(&str[begin], str.length() - begin);
            std::wstring converted = std::wstring(segment.size() + 1, 0);
            size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, segment.c_str(), segment.size(), &converted[0], converted.length());
            converted.resize(size);
            ret.append(converted);
        }

#elif LINUX_PLATFORM || MACOS_PLATFORM || EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM || CYGWIN_PLATFORM
        size_t size;
        pos = str.find(static_cast<char>(0), begin);
        while (pos != String::npos)
        {
            String segment = String(&str[begin], pos - begin);
            WString converted = WString(segment.size(), 0);
            size = mbstowcs(&converted[0], &segment[0], converted.size());
            converted.resize(size);
            ret.append(converted);
            ret.append({0});
            begin = pos + 1;
            pos = str.find(static_cast<char>(0), begin);
        }
        if (begin < str.length())
        {
            String segment = String(&str[begin], str.length() - begin);
            WString converted = WString(segment.size(), 0);
            size = mbstowcs(&converted[0], &segment[0], converted.size());
            converted.resize(size);
            ret.append(converted);
        }
#else
        static_assert(false, "Unknown Platform");
#endif
        return ret;
    }

    static WString ToUpper(const WString &data)
    {
        WString result = data;
        auto &f = std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t>>(std::locale());

        f.toupper(&result[0], &result[0] + result.size());
        return result;
    }

    static String ToUpper(const String &data)
    {
        return WideStringToString(ToUpper(StringToWideString(data)));
    }

    static WString ToLower(const WString &data)
    {
        WString result = data;
        auto &f = std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t>>(std::locale());
        f.tolower(&result[0], &result[0] + result.size());
        return result;
    }

    static String ToLower(const String &data)
    {
        return WideStringToString(ToLower(StringToWideString(data)));
    }
};

enum class ConsoleTextStyle
{
    DEFAULT = 0,
    BOLD = 1,
    FAINT = 2,
    ITALIC = 3,
    UNDERLINE = 4,
    SLOW_BLINK = 5,
    RAPID_BLINK = 6,
    REVERSE = 7,
};

enum class ConsoleForeground
{
    DEFAULT = 39,
    BLACK = 30,
    DARK_RED = 31,
    DARK_GREEN = 32,
    DARK_YELLOW = 33,
    DARK_BLUE = 34,
    DARK_MAGENTA = 35,
    DARK_CYAN = 36,
    GRAY = 37,
    DARK_GRAY = 90,
    RED = 91,
    GREEN = 92,
    YELLOW = 93,
    BLUE = 94,
    MAGENTA = 95,
    CYAN = 96,
    WHITE = 97
};

enum class ConsoleBackground
{
    DEFAULT = 49,
    BLACK = 40,
    DARK_RED = 41,
    DARK_GREEN = 42,
    DARK_YELLOW = 43,
    DARK_BLUE = 44,
    DARK_MAGENTA = 45,
    DARK_CYAN = 46,
    GRAY = 47,
    DARK_GRAY = 100,
    RED = 101,
    GREEN = 102,
    YELLOW = 103,
    BLUE = 104,
    MAGENTA = 105,
    CYAN = 106,
    WHITE = 107
};

class Console
{
private:
    static void EnableVirtualTermimalProcessing()
    {
#if WINDOWS_PLATFORM
        HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        DWORD dwMode = 0;
        GetConsoleMode(hOut, &dwMode);
        if (!(dwMode & ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING))
        {
            dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
            SetConsoleMode(hOut, dwMode);
        }
#endif
    }

    static void ResetTerminalFormat()
    {
        std::cout << u8"\033[0m";
    }

    static void SetVirtualTerminalFormat(ConsoleForeground foreground, ConsoleBackground background, std::set<ConsoleTextStyle> styles)
    {
        String format = u8"\033[";
        format.append(std::to_string(static_cast<int>(foreground)));
        format.append(u8";");
        format.append(std::to_string(static_cast<int>(background)));
        if (styles.size() > 0)
        {
            for (auto it = styles.begin(); it != styles.end(); ++it)
            {
                format.append(u8";");
                format.append(std::to_string(static_cast<int>(*it)));
            }
        }
        format.append(u8"m");
        std::cout << format;
    }

public:
    static void Clear()
    {

#if WINDOWS_PLATFORM 
        std::system(u8"cls");
#elif LINUX_PLATFORM || defined MACOS_PLATFORM || CYGWIN_PLATFORM
        std::system(u8"clear");
#elif EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM
        emscripten::val::global()["console"].call<void>(u8"clear");
#else
        static_assert(false, "Unknown Platform");
#endif
    }

    static void Write(const String &s, ConsoleForeground foreground = ConsoleForeground::DEFAULT, ConsoleBackground background = ConsoleBackground::DEFAULT, std::set<ConsoleTextStyle> styles = {})
    {
#ifndef EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM
        EnableVirtualTermimalProcessing();
        SetVirtualTerminalFormat(foreground, background, styles);
#endif
        String str = s;
#if WINDOWS_PLATFORM
        WString unicode = Strings::StringToWideString(str);
        WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), unicode.c_str(), static_cast<DWORD>(unicode.length()), nullptr, nullptr);
#elif defined LINUX_PLATFORM || defined MACOS_PLATFORM || EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM || CYGWIN_PLATFORM
        std::cout << str;
#else
        static_assert(false, "Unknown Platform");
#endif

#ifndef EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM
        ResetTerminalFormat();
#endif
    }

    static void WriteLine(const String &s, ConsoleForeground foreground = ConsoleForeground::DEFAULT, ConsoleBackground background = ConsoleBackground::DEFAULT, std::set<ConsoleTextStyle> styles = {})
    {
        Write(s, foreground, background, styles);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    static void Write(const WString &s, ConsoleForeground foreground = ConsoleForeground::DEFAULT, ConsoleBackground background = ConsoleBackground::DEFAULT, std::set<ConsoleTextStyle> styles = {})
    {
#ifndef EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM
        EnableVirtualTermimalProcessing();
        SetVirtualTerminalFormat(foreground, background, styles);
#endif
        WString str = s;

#if WINDOWS_PLATFORM 
        WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), str.c_str(), static_cast<DWORD>(str.length()), nullptr, nullptr);
#elif LINUX_PLATFORM || MACOS_PLATFORM || EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM || CYGWIN_PLATFORM
        std::cout << Strings::WideStringToString(str);
#else
        static_assert(false, "Unknown Platform");
#endif

#ifndef EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM
        ResetTerminalFormat();
#endif
    }

    static void WriteLine(const WString &s, ConsoleForeground foreground = ConsoleForeground::DEFAULT, ConsoleBackground background = ConsoleBackground::DEFAULT, std::set<ConsoleTextStyle> styles = {})
    {
        Write(s, foreground, background, styles);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    static void WriteLine()
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    static void Pause()
    {
        char c;
        do
        {
            c = getchar();
            std::cout << "Press Key " << std::endl;
        } while (c != 64);
        std::cout << "KeyPressed" << std::endl;
    }

    static int PauseAny(bool printWhenPressed = false, ConsoleForeground foreground = ConsoleForeground::DEFAULT, ConsoleBackground background = ConsoleBackground::DEFAULT, std::set<ConsoleTextStyle> styles = {})
    {
        int ch;
#ifdef WINDOWS_PLATFORM
        ch = _getch();
#elif LINUX_PLATFORM || MACOS_PLATFORM || EMSCRIPTEN_PLATFORM || CYGWIN_PLATFORM
        struct termios oldt, newt;
        tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
        newt = oldt;
        newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
        ch = getchar();
        tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
#else
        static_assert(false, "Unknown Platform");
#endif
        if (printWhenPressed)
        {
            Console::Write(String(1, ch), foreground, background, styles);
        }
        return ch;
    }
};

int main()
{
#if CYGWIN_PLATFORM
    /*
    using c++ std::locale::global(). It generates an error.
    
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
    what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid

    it need to be fixed.
    */
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, u8"en_US.UTF8"); //Calling clasic C locale function all OK. Needed for Console::WriteLine on Linux. If not present throws an error and if not is a unicode locale throws an error. It need to be fixed.
#else
    std::locale::global(std::locale(u8"en_US.UTF8")); //Required for Linux. Error when run without set unicode locale. This need to be investigated and fixed.
#endif
    String dataStr = u8"Zoë Saldaña played in La maldición del padre Cardona. ëèñ αω óóChloë";
    WString dataWStr = L"Zoë Saldaña played in La maldición del padre Cardona. ëèñ αω óóChloë";
    Console::WriteLine(dataStr);
    Console::WriteLine(dataWStr);
    dataStr = Strings::ToUpper(dataStr);
    dataWStr = Strings::ToUpper(dataWStr);
    Console::WriteLine(dataStr);
    Console::WriteLine(dataWStr);
    dataStr = Strings::ToLower(dataStr);
    dataWStr = Strings::ToLower(dataWStr);
    Console::WriteLine(dataStr);
    Console::WriteLine(dataWStr);

    //Another examples
    WString string0(L"hello there είναι απλά ένα κείμενο χωρίς");
    WString string1(L"hallo Привет");
    WString string2(L"Hallo Привет");
    WString string3(L"HALLO ПРИВЕТ");
    WString string4 = L"Contrairement à une opinion répandue ";

    Console::WriteLine(u8"█ Original");
    Console::WriteLine(string0);
    Console::WriteLine(string1);
    Console::WriteLine(string2);
    Console::WriteLine(string3);
    Console::WriteLine(string4);

    Console::WriteLine(u8"█ ToUpper");
    string0 = Strings::ToUpper(string0);
    string1 = Strings::ToUpper(string1);
    string2 = Strings::ToUpper(string2);
    string3 = Strings::ToUpper(string3);
    string4 = Strings::ToUpper(string4);
    Console::WriteLine(string0);
    Console::WriteLine(string1);
    Console::WriteLine(string2);
    Console::WriteLine(string3);
    Console::WriteLine(string4);

    Console::WriteLine(u8"█ ToLower");
    string0 = Strings::ToLower(string0);
    string1 = Strings::ToLower(string1);
    string2 = Strings::ToLower(string2);
    string3 = Strings::ToLower(string3);
    string4 = Strings::ToLower(string4);
    Console::WriteLine(string0);
    Console::WriteLine(string1);
    Console::WriteLine(string2);
    Console::WriteLine(string3);
    Console::WriteLine(string4);

    Console::WriteLine(u8"Press any key to exit"s, ConsoleForeground::DARK_GRAY);
    Console::PauseAny();

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Zoë Saldaña played in La maldición del padre Cardona. ëèñ αω óóChloë
Zoë Saldaña played in La maldición del padre Cardona. ëèñ αω óóChloë
ZOË SALDAÑA PLAYED IN LA MALDICIÓN DEL PADRE CARDONA. ËÈÑ ΑΩ ÓÓCHLOË
ZOË SALDAÑA PLAYED IN LA MALDICIÓN DEL PADRE CARDONA. ËÈÑ ΑΩ ÓÓCHLOË
zoë saldaña played in la maldición del padre cardona. ëèñ αω óóchloë
zoë saldaña played in la maldición del padre cardona. ëèñ αω óóchloë
█ Original
hello there είναι απλά ένα κείμενο χωρίς
hallo Привет
Hallo Привет
HALLO ПРИВЕТ
Contrairement à une opinion répandue 
█ ToUpper
HELLO THERE ΕΊΝΑΙ ΑΠΛΆ ΈΝΑ ΚΕΊΜΕΝΟ ΧΩΡΊΣ
HALLO ПРИВЕТ
HALLO ПРИВЕТ
HALLO ПРИВЕТ
CONTRAIREMENT À UNE OPINION RÉPANDUE 
█ ToLower
hello there είναι απλά ένα κείμενο χωρίσ
hallo привет
hallo привет
hallo привет
contrairement à une opinion répandue 
Press any key to exit
```

---

**Compiled with Visual C++ compiler - Powershell and CMD's output using Windows Terminal - Correct drawing ✔️**

[image: wt]

---

**Compiled with Visual C++ compiler - pure cmd's output - Partial drawing ❗**

[image: cmd]

---

**Compiled with Visual C++ compiler - pure PowerShell's output - Partial drawing ❗**

[image: pwsh]

---

**Compiled with Clang++ in WSL Ubuntu 20.04 - Visual Studio Code's output - Correct drawing ✔️**

[image: wsl]

---

**Compiled with g++(Cygwin) - Visual Studio code's Output + CygwinTerminal's output + Windows Terminal's output - Correct drawing ✔️ different glyps rendering**

[image: all]

---

**Compiled with Visual C++ compiler - Visual Studio 2019's output - Correct drawing ✔️**

[image: vs]

Comment: I must have a weird system but this is not working for me on Windows nor under Cygwin. The Cygwin version does not produce any output after `std::locale::global(std::locale(u8"en_US.UTF-8"));` and on Windows the Latin text is OK but the rest is completely garbled.

Comment: I added the code to detect cygwin and I had to adapt the part of std::locale:: global since in cygwin it causes an error. I had to use std::setlocale instead. I recommend run your compiled programs in the Windows Terminal.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/

Comment: The setting for Cygwin `std::setlocale(LC_ALL, u8"en_US.UTF8");` gives for Cygwin the results I'm looking for. For windows itself I see that you are successful but I still get garbled output for the Greek and Cyrillic text, Any idea?

Comment: 1.- Windows Terminal [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/], but it needs Windows 10 version 18362.0 or higher  [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab]. - Example: wt.exe ConsoleApplication.exe  
2.- ConEmu [https://conemu.github.io/]

Comment: The first and second link give a 404 error. The windows 10 version I have is higher than the mentioned version. Is theer a 3rd terminal type supported by Microsoft, besides the good old cmd and the PowerShell. For normal usage I prefer the cmd.

Comment: If you prefer to avoid headaches, I recommend Windows Terminal, it has support for unicode and UTF-8. Inside Windows Terminal you can set default terminal app cmd or powershell or WSL or cygwin, etc. 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/ 

Example if you are outside Windows terminal and need to run your program with it. wt.exe ./ConsoleApplication.exe

Comment: Unfortunately it is not just for me but also for other, unknown to me, people.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

edit: I just read that [you should not use `wchar_t` for unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17871934), so this answer is not complete.

See my duplicate tag

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using std::wcout;
using std::wstring;
#define endl '\n'

int main() {
    std::locale::global(std::locale("en_US.UTF8"));
    std::wcout.imbue(std::locale());
    auto& f = std::use_facet<std::ctype<wchar_t>>(std::locale());

    wstring string0(L"hello there είναι απλά ένα κείμενο χωρίς");
    wstring string1(L"hallo Привет");
    wstring string2(L"Hallo Привет");
    wstring string3(L"HALLO ПРИВЕТ");

    wstring output0 = string0;
    f.toupper(&output0[0], &output0[output0.size()]);
    wcout << "input string:  " << string0 << endl
         << "output string: " << output0 << endl;

    wstring output1 = string1;
    f.toupper(&output1[0], &output1[output1.size()]);
    wcout << "input string:  " << string1 << endl
         << "output string: " << output1 << endl;

    wstring output2 = string2;
    f.toupper(&output2[0], &output2[output2.size()]);
    wcout << "input string:  " << string2 << endl
         << "output string: " << output2 << endl;

    wstring output3 = string3;
    f.toupper(&output3[0], &output3[output3.size()]);
    wcout << "input string:  " << string3 << endl
         << "output string: " << output3 << endl;

    wstring string4 = L"Contrairement à une opinion répandue";

    wstring output4 = string4;
    f.toupper(&output4[0], &output4[output4.size()]);
    wcout << "input string:  " << string4 << endl
         << "output string: " << output4 << endl;
}
```

returns

```
input string:  hello there είναι απλά ένα κείμενο χωρίς
output string: HELLO THERE ΕΊΝΑΙ ΑΠΛΆ ΈΝΑ ΚΕΊΜΕΝΟ ΧΩΡΊΣ
input string:  hallo Привет
output string: HALLO ПРИВЕТ
input string:  Hallo Привет
output string: HALLO ПРИВЕТ
input string:  HALLO ПРИВЕТ
output string: HALLO ПРИВЕТ
input string:  Contrairement à une opinion répandue
output string: CONTRAIREMENT À UNE OPINION RÉPANDUE
```

Comment: I see your edit now (after starting some tests, so still a bit of feedback). Looks promising, though when I compile and run (Cygwin) I don't get any output at all. When compiling with visual C (Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27034 for x86) I get some output but it is all garbled.

Comment: @albert yes, sorry, also learning here. Changing everything to `char` keeps all the special characters lowercase... I still expect the answer somewhere there.